# Метки "шаблоны" и "template"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

У недавнего [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546121/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8) есть 2 схожие метки: [template](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template) и [шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b). Вероятно, их следует объединить в одну, добавив при этом соответствующее описание для метки. Однако существуют вопросы с аналогичными метками и по темам web-технологий. Надо это тоже учесть в описании метки, или придется убрать/переименовать эту метку у таких вопросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метки [синонимизированы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

**Предложение:**

### Уничтожить обе, как слишком неконкретные

Сейчас эти метки охватывают несколько существенно разных областей, и подписаться только на одну из них не представляется возможным, а если исключить С++, то интересным тоже не выглядит.

Заменить на [c++-template](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-template) (в честь ключевого слова в языке), где уместно.

Где речь о **шаблонизаторе**, указать более конкретные метки о конкретных шаблонизаторах или связанных технологиях, вроде [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress), [haml](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haml), [jade](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jade)/[pug](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pug) и т. п. В некоторых случаях подходящие метки уже проставлены.

**Необходимости в более общей метке [шаблонизатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80) не вижу**, поскольку не могу придумать хорошего вопроса по теме (достаточно конкретного и не *"подберите шаблонизатор под нужды <список>"*), касающегося шаблонизаторов в целом.

Comment: На enSO [метка](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/templates/info) соответствует только c++ (для web предлагаются более частные случаи). Ну и название в множественном числе. Вопрос ещё в том, нужно ли делать подобные метки на русском языке. Или строить их на базе ключевых слов ЯП.

Comment: @alexolut ситуация с этими метками на enSO сильно печальнее, вмешавшись сейчас, мы можем это предотвратить. Я предлагаю строить метку на основе ключевого слова по той причине, что с ним не может быть разногласий, оно есть в языке и все спрашивающие по этой теме это слово знают (я надеюсь!). На русском я слышал варианты "шаблоны" и "темплейты", последний не вижу смысла поддерживать, а [tag:шаблоны-c++] можно добавить синонимом.

Comment: Похоже, метки уже удалены отовсюду?