# О метке "шаблоны"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Вопрос в принципе [поднимался](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3409/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B8-template), но и сейчас в описании метки [шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b) описываются "шаблоны проектирования". А применяется метка очень активно для "шаблонов С++".

Увы, простого решения предложить не могу. Только поднять вопрос, что с этим нужно что-то делать.

Мне кажется, что именно по шаблонам проектирования (в литературе они же "паттерны", они же "проектные шаблоны") эта метка применена реже, чем к шаблонам C++. Поэтому, наверное, меньше работы ввести новую метку "шаблоны-проектирования", проставив ее там, где идет речь о них, а эту, переписав описание, оставить за шаблонами C++ (или изменить ее на "шаблоны-C++" или "templates").

Может, стоит заняться, пока метка применена еще менее 400 раз? :)

Answer (score 13):

[шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b) вообще нужно бы выпилить, как слишком неконкретный. Оставить только [шаблоны-проектирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) (хотя, шаблоны могут быть не только проектирования...) и [шаблоны-c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-c%2b%2b).

Comment: Нельзя выпиливать «шаблоны». Эту метку снова создадут быстро. Нужно синонимизировать и делать её второстепенной.

Comment: @alexolut второстепенной к той, что покрывает большую часть вопросов?

Comment: Чисто исходя из того, чтобы меньше править. Но может быть это не лучший вариант, учитывая, что участники бездумно вставляют метку, а мы пойдем у них на поводу.

Answer (score 6):

Предлагаю заменить все вхождения [шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b) на [шаблоны-проектирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) и [шаблоны-c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-c%2b%2b).

Comment: дубликат ответа от `Suvitruf` ?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, [нет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6433/timeline) (спасибо alexolut за то, что [указал на это](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41352494#41352494)).

Comment: странно что у вас тогда голосов меньше

Comment: @FoggyFinder, этого я не знаю. По крайней мере один из шести голосов «за» мой (проголосовал после удаления своего ответа).

Comment: Не везде текущая метка «шаблоны» покрывается предложенными двумя.

Answer (score 4):

Случайно наткнулся на метку [архитектура](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0) и увидел там такое описание:

> Вопросы об архитектуре программного обеспечения и Software Engineering, в том числе о **шаблонах проектирования**.

Проблема в том, что задающий вопрос о паттернах проектирования вряд ли найдет метку «архитектура». Чтобы это произошло, надо вероятно синонимизоровать с «архитектурой» и ту метку, которая будет использоваться для «шаблонов проектирования». Либо вынести из «архитектуры» вопросы о шаблонах.

Сейчас на метку «шаблоны» (проектирования) выводится больше вопросов о вэб-шаблонизаторах, т.е. люди не читают описание метки и лепят её сугубо по названию. Наиболее правильный выход отсюда, как мне кажется, убрать вовсе метку «шаблоны» (из списка основных), так как её название слишком общее и использовать частные метки «шаблоны-проектирования», «шаблоны-с++», «шаблоны-php» и т.д. В итоге, даже если автор задаст метку «шаблоны», она отобразится в вопросе иначе (зависит от того, с чем синонимизируем) и с большой вероятностью будет исправлена на более подходящую, если это потребуется.

То есть, метку «шаблоны» не убирать, так как велика вероятность, что её создадут снова, а сделать её второстепенным синонимом. Посмотреть по количеству вопросов, к чему именно, чтобы уменьшить количество изменений меток в вопросах.

Стоит заметить, что сейчас уже наблюдается наличие двух несвязанных меток с практически одинаковым описанием:

> [image: шаблоны]

В общем, надо наводить порядок.